# React-router nested routes re rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, use-effect, rerender

My react app uses a context and its state can  be changed from another component. Here is the route setup

```js
<Router>
                <NavBar />
                <Switch>
                    <PostsProvider>
                        <Route exact path='/posts'>
                            <Posts />
                        </Route>{" "}
                        <Route exact path='/stats'>
                            <Stats />
                        </Route>
                    </PostsProvider>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
```

And the context is setup to only redo things when this happens

```js
const [loadPosts, setLoadPosts] = useState(true);
    useEffect(
        function () {
            fetchPosts();
        },
        [loadPosts]
    );
```

loadpost is changed from the `posts` component but the weird part is, `stats` component re renders every time the route changes despite it having an empty array in the useEffect of every sub component like this

```js
    useEffect(function () {
        fetchData();
    }, []);
```

And the navlinks are wrapped with `Link`
Any sugesstions to why this happens? and can i prevent it?

Comment: What do you mean by `stats component re renders every time the route changes`? Do you mean that you go from `/stats` to `/posts` and then back to `/stats` and after that `fetchData()` is called? If so, then it's because the components is removed from the DOM and then created again - therefore sob-component `useEffect` is called, because it's completely new instance.

Comment: yes but if i go to ```/posts``` after that post does not re render. Which is weird because i dont remember this being the case before. Any way I can prevent it?

Comment: I am not sure why it works like this for you. Here's my attempt to recreate it: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-cray-tmsp4?file=/src/App.js and as you could see in console, components get's re-rendered everytime when nav link is clicked (other than current), as expected. You would need to share more code to find an issue.

Comment: i cant see any code that would make your example do anything. And all the tutorials i have watched it does not rerender for them as well. because. useEffect(func, []) means that when the component mounts and thats it. as it is an empty array, there is no dependencies meaning nothing changed even if it is unmounted again and remounted. maybe i am wrong but it did work for me before.

Comment: Okay so for now I fixed it with a check to see if items have already been loaded but if there is an explanation please inform me. I remember using it without this issue before,

Comment: Sorry, I didn't save the example, please check now! So as you wrote, your component is unmounted and then mounted again - this means that it's a new instance, so new `useEffect()` function is created. Since it's new it would be called - just once, because of empty dependencies list, but would still be called after every new mount. I honestly don't know why it worked differently for you, as it shouldn't - maybe the code was different?

Comment: I would have revisited the code but sadly i don't have access to it. I maybe wrong. If you're right I suppose the method i applied is the only way to solve it.

Comment: thanks for the discussion though. really helpful

Comment: although. that still doesn't explain the fact that another component ```posts``` works as I expect even when I move away from ut

Comment: The sandbox should be public, you cannot see the code here? https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-cray-tmsp4?file=/src/App.js You would need to share more code to find an issue I suppose.